# How do I compare 2 boolean variables in shell in If statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

This is the scenario:

```
# Initialization 
var1=true
var2=true

#
#
#
var1=false
var2=false 
#
#

if [[var1==false && var2==false]]
then
   echo "Both vars are false"
fi
```

no matter what the value is in var1 and var2, the program is entering the if statement. How do I fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Instead, I get `bash: [[var1==false: command not found` regardless, and it's *not* entering the if statement.

Comment: Specify the error message in your question (no comment).

Comment: There is no error message. No matter what var1 and var2 holds, true true, true false, false true or false false, it is entering that If block. which is not supposed to happen

Comment: don't bother using text comparisons. There are literal commands, `true` and `false`, so you can say `if $var1 && $var2 ; then`, which will be transformed into `if true && true ; then` ...(or if `varX=false` you'll get the appropriate behavior). Good luck.

Comment: AND do you need to use `$var1` in your existing code, or does `[[ ... ]]` work like `(( ... ))` where the `$`s aren't needed?

Comment: @daylightsaving Can you please copy-paste the code from your own post into a new file and try again? Make sure not to reuse any of your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the '[[' conditional expression, elements of the expressions need to be entered as separate tokens, separated by white spaces. Also, variables need to be prefixed by '$'. The condition can be fixed by adding '$' when referencing variables, and separating the '[['. ']]' and '==' with spaces

```
if [[ $var1 == false && $var2 == false ]]
then
   echo "Both vars are false"
fi
```

Comment: thank you. you're right, I had missed few white spaces